# 2 text fields to always equal 100 percent xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextfield

I have two text fields that are for percentages to be entered in.  If i put 20 in the first field I would like the second text field to be updated to 60.  And later on if I changed the second one to say 30, I would like the first updated to 70.

For ease of showing what I mean, say I have two text fields _firstPercent and _secondPercent with associated labels _firstTotal and _secondTotal:

```
float firstPercent = [_firstPercent.text floatValue];

float firstAmount = (firstSalePercent / 100) * firstOrigonalAmount;

_firstTotal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",firstAmount];



float secondPercent = [_secondPercent.text floatValue];

float secondAmount = (secondSalePercent / 100) * secondOrigonalAmount;

_secondTotal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",secondAmount];
```

I really don't know how to handle this so I tried adding this below its respective code.  It works for the first one, but not the second.

```
float percentToSecond = 100 - firstPercent;
_secondPercent.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f", percentToSecond];

float percentToFirst = 100 - secondPercent;
_firstPercent.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f", percentToFirst];
```

I have tried other solutions but don't know what to do.

I would just like someone to lead me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the delegate method controlTextDidEndEditing: to see what value was entered, and then set the value for the other text field.  In the following code tf1 and tf2 are the IBOutlets for the two text fields.

```
    -(void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)obj {
    float value = [[[obj.userInfo valueForKey:@"NSFieldEditor"] string] floatValue];
    if (obj.object == self.tf1) {
        self.tf2.stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",100. - value];
    }else if (obj.object == self.tf2) {
        self.tf1.stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",100. - value];
    }
}
```

You'd have to do some more checking to make sure the user didn't enter a number greater than 100 or something not a number.

Comment: I have been trying to make this work for hours along with reading Apple documentation etc.  Is controlTextDidEndEditing for OS X.  And I would need to use textFieldDidEndEditing for ios?

Comment: Sorry about that -- yes you would use textFieldDidEndEditing for iOS, and make sure you set your class where you have this code to the delegate of the text field.

Comment: Thanks!!   I have the basic code working for tf1 and tf2.  This helped a lot.